# Python does not stop reading from stdin buffer

Tags: python, node.js, pipe, buffer, stdin

In Node.JS, I spawn a child Python process to be piped. I want to send a UInt8Array through stdin. So as to notify the size of the buffer data to be read, I send the size of it before. But it doesn't stop reading for the actual data from the buffer properly after a specified size. As a result, the Python process doesn't terminate forever. I've checked that it takes bufferSize properly and converts it into an integer. In the absence of `size = int(input())` and `python.stdin.write(bufferSize.toString() + "\n")` and when the size of the buffer is hardcoded, it works correctly. I couldn't figure out why it does not end waiting after reading for the specified amount of bytes.

```
// Node.JS
const python_command = command.serializeBinary()
const python = spawn('test/production_tests/py_test_scripts/protocolbuffer/venv/bin/python', ['test/production_tests/py_test_scripts/protocolbuffer/command_handler.py']);

const bufferSize = python_command.byteLength
python.stdin.write(bufferSize.toString() + "\n")
python.stdin.write(python_command)
```

```
# Python
size = int(input())
data = sys.stdin.buffer.read(size)
```

In a nutshell, the problem arises from the fact that putting normal stdin `input()` firstly and then `sys.stdin.buffer.read`. I guess the preceding one conflicts with the successive one and precludes it to work normally.

Comment: `python_command` is binary data.  The size of it can be found with `.byteLength`.

Comment: You have: `const bufferSize = 5`. Is this the hardcoded version that works? If so, please show the version that doesn't work

Comment: No, my problem has to do with not being able to end buffer reading as I want.

Comment: I think you need to close `stdin` with `python.stdin.end()` to indicate that there is no more input to read.

Comment: No, it is not needed since I specified the size of data to be read.

Comment: In that case, instead of `sys.stdin.buffer.read(size)` if all your messages are going to be newline delimited, consider `sys.stdin.buffer.readline()`.  Then you won't need to tell Python how long the message is.  You might still need to flush on the Node side.

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential problems here. The first is that the pipe between node.js and the python script is block buffered. You won't see any data on the python side until either a block's worth of data is filled (system dependent) or the pipe is closed. The second is that there is a decoder between `input` and the byte stream coming in on stdin. This decoder is free to read ahead in the stream as it wishes. Reading `sys.stdin.buffer` may miss whatever happens to be buffered in the decoder.

You can solve the second problem by doing all of your reads from the buffer as shown below. The first problem needs to be solved on the node.js side - likely by closing its subprocess stdin. You may be better off just writing the size as a binary number, say uint64.

```
import struct
import sys

# read size - assuming its coming in as ascii stream
size_buf = []
while True:
    c = sys.stdin.buffer.read(1)
    if c == b"\n":
        size = int(b"".join(size_buf))
        break
    size_buf.append(c)

fmt = "B" # read unsigned char
fmtsize = struct.calcsize(fmt)
buf = [struct.unpack(fmt, sys.stdin.buffer.read(fmtsize))[0] for _ in range(size)]
print(buf)
```

Comment: I cannot close the subprocess, it must stay open until Node.JS has terminated.

Comment: Is there an option for `stdin.buffer` to stop after a certain character has reached Python like `'\n'`?

Comment: Does the subprocess need to keep consuming data? If not, just close its stdin. I don't think that stdin.buffer will scan for a `'\n`. The while loop I showed does that. In this example, if it reads 0 bytes signalling stdin is closed, the `struct.unpack` will raise an error.

Comment: Yes, it needs to keep consuming data. But I got your point, thanks. The answer is buffer data does not lend a mechanism to cease the stream of data. So I send data as a raw string and end it with '\n'.

Comment: You could also use something like zeromq https://zeromq.org/languages/nodejs/ to do the low level stuff for you.